# Populate Select Dropdown with Thousand of Records

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to populate select option dropdown with thousand records? I have almost 10,000 records and when I populate the select dropdown with these records it hangs. Even I have tried using ajax but nothing works?.

Comment: Nobody is going to use a dropdown with 1,000 items, let alone 10,000. You need some other way of drilling down the records to the one the user wants.

Comment: no one wants to scroll through 10k records, think of a better UI

Comment: I guess you could take a "search" in your database basing on user writing only. Don't load entire records

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bad idea to use a drop down to select from so many choices.